# How do I escape values in SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am writing some SpEL statements in XML, and I can't get the parser to determine when I need to escape a character.

I've attempted the following:

```
<... property="someProperty" value="#{ someBean.aMethodOnTheBean('st\'ring') }" />
```

However adding in the \' does not seem to escape that single quote and I keep receiving a parser exception.

Is there any way to escape these values?

Comment: #{someBean.aMethodOnTheBean(T(org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils).escapeJavaScript("ad'sf")) } Works, but is not very clean

Comment: Nice attempt! BTW, that approach is documented in an example over the [expression templating section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-templating).

Comment: Also, that might be an option to who is using [spring property placeholder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-property-placeholder-configurer-a-few-not-so-obvious-options.html) (although I couldn't figure it out how to properly use it in that situation, so I ended up escaping the values at the `.properties` file directly).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

> "To put a single quote itself in a
>   string use two single quote
>   characters."

`expression = 'something = ''' + someMethod.getValue + ''''`

Answer (score 0):

I modified to:

```
.... value="#{ someBean.aMethodOnTheBean("st'ring") }"
```

This works, I remembered incorrectly that I had issues when using a double quote to input a string value into a SpEL function prior.

Below is the schema definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true"
       default-init-method="initialize">
```

The XML validates properly in eclipse.  However my simplified example was not valid -- my apologies and good catch.  I am actually setting the value like this:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="someClass">
    <property name="someList">
        <list>
            <value>"#{ anotherBean.methodOnBean("some'String") }"</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is the content on SO corrupt somehow or did I get you wrong? I am pretty sure: `<something value="#{"a"}"  />` is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, SpEL has support for double-quotes as of version 3.2.
[SPR-9620](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9620)