# Spring Spel XPATH Expression for Namespace but no prefix

Tags: spring, xpath, spring-el

Issue: Trying to build the correct XPATH using SpEL xpath to correlate on a the "Name" tag value where the root tag has a namespace but no prefix.

Error: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'identifier'
It's complaining about & #39; where I am trying to make a single quote for the xpath evaluation.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.foo.com">
<id></id>
<Name>test</Name>
</root>
```

Spring Config

```
<aggregator 
    id="agg1" 
    input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="outputChannel" 
    discard-channel="garbageCanChannel"
    ref="blah" 
    method="combine"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()]=&#39;Name&#39;/text()')"
    release-strategy="blah"
    release-strategy-method="timeToRelease"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
    send-timeout="60000"
    group-timeout="60000"
    />
```

Update:

So after downloading spring source and tracing the issue. It's seem that during the tokenization execution in the method below, Spring is treating the "Name" as a identifier instead of as part of the string literal. At least this is the difference between a working instance and a failing instance.Most likely i'm not escaping it correctly.

Class:InternalSpelExpressionParser.java
Method:doParseExpression

```
this.expressionString = "#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()=Name]')"//This works
[[HASH(#)](0,1), [IDENTIFIER:xpath](1,6), [LPAREN(()](6,7), [IDENTIFIER:payload](7,14), [COMMA(,)](14,15), [LITERAL_STRING:'//*[local-name()=Name]'](16,45), [RPAREN())](45,46)]


this.expressionString = "#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()='Name']')"//Thisfails
[[HASH(#)](0,1), [IDENTIFIER:xpath](1,6), [LPAREN(()](6,7), [IDENTIFIER:payload](7,14), [COMMA(,)](14,15), [LITERAL_STRING:'//*[local-name()='](16,35), [IDENTIFIER:Name](35,44), [LITERAL_STRING:']'](44,47), [RPAREN())](47,48)]
```

**Solution:**
...

```
correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(payload, '//*[local-name()=''Name'']/text()')"
```

Correct String Literal:
-You can see that it is now correct because the tokenization process is putting everything within the string literal token.

```
[[HASH(#)](0,1), [IDENTIFIER:xpath](1,6), [LPAREN(()](6,7), [IDENTIFIER:payload](7,14), [COMMA(,)](14,15), [LITERAL_STRING:'//*[local-name()=''Name'']/text()'](16,56), [RPAREN())](56,57)]
```

Additional Debug Notes:

When pulling out the spring git here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework

1. Take all of the projects.
2. At the root is "import=into-eclipse.bat" or "import-into-idea" that I did not see. You can execute that to fully build and check-out everything you need locally and import the projects so you can trace a issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression as posted will produces invalid XPath. It should have closing square bracket just before `/text()` instead :

```
'//*[local-name()=&#39;Name&#39;]/text()'
```

Or *maybe* using double single-quotes to escape, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308247/how-do-i-escape-values-in-spel) :

```
'//*[local-name()=''Name'']/text()'
```

Comment: I tried both above and I still got the same error. I know it's probably something small I am missing. Trying to find a xpath expression in spring that uses local-name() but haven't found an example yet.

Comment: Ya you were right on the the two single quote. I had messed up the copy and paste to try and didn't realize till I traced the issue to the Tokenization process in Spring. Ugh. Oh well very interesting to trace.