# How to escape a & character in spring Spel Evaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

I have an expression that contains a single & and spring spel evaluator keeps throwing the error  `missing expected character '&'`

I have tried using backslash and double backslash to escape it but then it gives illegal escape character error.

This is my expression that I need to parse

```
(#PaymentType!=null&&!(#PaymentType).toString().isEmpty()?'PaymentType:'+((#PaymentType)+' ')+'$':'')+(#ProductSearchState!=null&&!(#ProductSearchState).toString().isEmpty()?'ProductSearchState:'+((#ProductSearchState)+' ')+'$':'')+(#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address!=null&&!(#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address).toString().isEmpty()?'Manufacturer's Name & Address:'+((#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address)+' '):'')
```

Following is the code I am using to parse the expression .

```
 public static void main (String args[]) {
   String expression="(#PaymentType!=null&&!(#PaymentType).toString().isEmpty()?'PaymentType:'+((#PaymentType)+' ')+'$':'')+(#ProductSearchState!=null&&!(#ProductSearchState).toString().isEmpty()?'ProductSearchState:'+((#ProductSearchState)+' ')+'$':'')+(#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address!=null&&!(#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address).toString().isEmpty()?'Manufacturer's Name & Address:'+((#Manufacturer_s39s_s32Name_s32_s38_s32Address)+' '):'')";
   String g = expression;
   System.out.println(g);
        final Set<String> dependent = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

//        log.info("Extracting dependent attributes for {} ", expression);

            new SplExpressionVisitor<Void>() {
                public void visit(SpelExpression expression) {
                    visitNode(expression.getAST());
                }

                @Override
                protected Void visit(VariableReference node) {
                    final String variableReferenceName = getVariableReferenceName(node);
                    dependent.add(variableReferenceName);
                    return super.visit(node);
                }

            }.visit((SpelExpression) parser.parseExpression(expression));

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the double-slash \\ before the &?

Comment: @RubioRic yes i have. It given illegal escape character exception then.

Comment: if i place ////& before & then it works but then i have to remove the single quote in " Manufacturer's " . used / and // before the single quote to escape it. It still throws error

Comment: Maybe the problem is that single quote and not the &. Have you tried escaping that quote? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6206675/2553194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `'Manufacturer's Name & Address:'` looks like the string `'Manufacturer'` followed by some nonsense, as you can't use single quotation marks both to delimit the string as well as inside the string.

You need to use two single quote characters inside the string to escape it, like this:

```
'Manufacturer''s Name & Address:'
```

Refer to the "[Literal Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-literal)" section of the SpEL languauge reference documentation for more information about including literals in your expressions.